# In AdMob Rewarded Video Ad implementation, where to implement and set the reward item?

Tags: admob, rewardedvideoad

I followed instruction about the Rewarded Video Ads at https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video and checked the google ad sample code https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/RewardedVideoExample There is no issue to load the ad.

What I can't figure out is that the `RewardedVideoAdListener` interface has one method

```
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem)
```

How can I pass my rewardItem to the ad listener? I checked the Google API https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/package-summary, there is no api for me to pass my reward item.

Or am I completely wrong? Is this RewardItem controlled by AdMob system? If such case, what value do I expect from the RewardItem interface?

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardItem

Answer (score 0):

> what value do I expect from the RewardItem interface?

The **default** reward will have the amount of **1** and the type of **""**.
The **test** reward has the amount of 10 and the type of "coins".

> How can I pass my rewardItem to the ad listener?

To pass the reward item one should create a rewarded video ad unit, where "**Reward amount**" and "**Reward item**" should be set. Here is the guide: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7311747?hl=en .